# Moderator Back If you will have me :)

Tags: discussion

So where do I start exactly? I think I'll start with the an apology for vanishing as I did and thank those who reached out to see if I was okay. For the past year or more, real life have has been as crappy as it can be, from personal health issues requiring operations, to fatalities in the family. The good news is my health is good, and I'm good overall. I've had the time to reflect, repair, and become a better person inside and out.

I'd like to return. I can see I still have moderator status but obviously I didn't just want to dive straight back in, without saying anything, that would be weird right?

Comment: Yay! We've missed you!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear things were bad, that's what we were afraid of. But I'm glad you're healthy now in both body and spirit. While you were gone we decided that SEO was off-topic... :)

Comment: Thank's guys. SEO gone! WOW! it was always murky waters with many speculative answers.

Comment: Welcome back! :) Ha, I believe John had sarcastic tongue firmly in cheek! Still murky though!

Comment: Welcome back to Webmasters SE!

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm concerned,  **welcome back!**

Glad to hear that you're in good health and doing well. You missed quite a bit of drama and changes on the Stack Exchange network over the past year. Thankfully our site has remained fairly drama-free, so not much has changed here (with the exception of some updates to the Help page).

Be sure to sign the new moderator agreement when you get a chance, and get to modding! :-)

Comment: Thanks and Done :)